# Migrations fail but seems to be good in PHP LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel

I get back:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3780 Referencing column 'Categoria_id'
> and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint
> 'prodotti_categoria_id_foreign' are incompatible. (SQL: alter table
> `prodotti` add constraint `prodotti_categoria_id_foreign` foreign key
> (`Categoria_id`) references `categorie` (`id`))

but in my migrations data is:

```
// Categorie
 public function up()
    {
        //
        Schema::create('categorie', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('id')->autoIncrement();
            $table->string('Nome');
            $table->enum('Status',['Active','Disabled']);

        });
    }
// Prodotti:
public function up()
    {
        //
        Schema::create('prodotti', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('Marca');
            $table->string('Nome');
            $table->string('Descrizione');
            $table->bigInteger('EAN');
            $table->bigInteger('MINSAN');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->unsignedInteger('Categoria_id');
            $table->foreign('Categoria_id')->references('id')->on('categorie');
        });
    }
```

Comment: Hi,`Categoria_id` is `unsignedInteger`. It should be `unsignedBigInteger`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the type of `categoria_id` as bellow;

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('Categoria_id');
```

So it matches the foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

In `categoria`, you have the following:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('id')->autoIncrement();
```

In `prodotti` you have this:

```
$table->unsignedInteger('Categoria_id');
```

Notice how the type are different, one is `unsignedBigInteger` and the other is `unsignedInteger`. You'll have to use the same type.

Edit:

**Why is this an issue?**

Because `unsignedBigInteger` can grow more than `unsignedInteger` therefore you'll be at a point where the mapping will no longer be supported as one will continue to grow, but the other will have hit it's limit.